# Como retornar a formulario principal desde un User Control vb NET

Tags: vb.net, usercontrol

Ojalá alguien pueda ayudarme. Tengo lo siguiente en mi proyecto:

- Proyecto principal con un formulario llamado MenuPrincipal (winForm)
- Librería de clases .NET llamado LibA
  Dentro de esta librería tengo un UserControl llamado UC_Control
- Librería de clases .NET llamado Componente
  Dentro de esa librería tengo una interfaz llamada IModulos y una clase llamada Modulo.
  Dentro de esta interfaz tengo una propiedad publica de tipo User Control
  Dentro de la clase llamada Modulo tengo la implementación de dicha interfaz que hace referencia a la librería llamada LibA.

  Obviamente en la jerarquía de este proyecto, en la libreria Componente tengo referencia a la libreria LibA porque de otro modo no podría usarlo en la interfaz.

Ahora bien mi problema es el siguiente.

Desde mi form principal tengo un panel en el cual logro llamar al user control de LibA (a través de la interfaz de la dll llamada componente), pero lo que ahora requiero es como desde cualquier método, evento o función que yo programe en ese usercontrol UC_Control, pueda yo retornar o ejecutar cualquier evento, función o método de mi formulario principal (MenuPrincipal) en vb.

No sé si me dí a entender. Si alguien requiere puedo poner algunas capturas.

De lo anterior dicho, lo que pretendo conseguir es lo siguiente:

Menu principal con opciones, si clikeo una opción del menú, me lanza opciones como submenú, si yo clikeo una opción del submenú quiero lanzar un módulo (user control) cuando quiera cerrar ese módulo, quiero regresar (dependiendo de la circunstancias o criterio de lógica) al sub menú o menu principal.

**EDIT**

Conseguí una solución rápida aunque no es lo que necesito, y quisiera que alguien más supiera una manera más pragmática de hacerlo.

Lo que hice fue que en el evento Load de mi formulario principal tuviera que usar un AddHandler de la siguiente manera:

```
AddHandler Instancia.PropiedadDeLaInterfaz.Controls.Item("NombreDelControl").Click, AddressOf CualquierMétodoDelFormularioPrincipal
```

Lo que yo necesito es algo más como una forma correcta de usar la interfaz o algo pueda heredar el objeto como tal pero pasando por el intermediario que es una libreria de componentes. Todos los proyectos se encuentran en la misma solución pero están separados y los comunico o mando a llamar todo através de librerias.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Lo que no entiendo es cual es el problema. Una referencia al padre alcanza. o eventos. O cualquier otro medio de comunicacion entre controles que se te ocurra.

Comment: @gbianchi muchas gracias por la bienvenida y tomaré muy en cuenta tu sugerencia para futuras referencias. De lo anterior que comentaste, te comento lo siguiente. No puedo hacer referencia porque en el proyecto principal ya tengo una referencia (lib dll llamada Componente) en el que ya está referenciado la otra dll donde esta el user control y si intento hacer lo que tu dices (que es correcto) vs no deja por incidencia de dependencia circular. De hecho logré resolverlo aunque no me gusta el modo. Sigo esperando una sugerencia mejor.

Comment: Lee ahora los links que te pase.. como es que lo solucionaste? ponelo en una respuesta, o por ejemplo aclaralo en tu pregunta (si no, es probable que te dan la misma respuesta). Tene en cuenta que asi como esta la pregunta puede ser cerrada, ya que es muy amplia

Comment: @gbianchi edité mi post, y ojalá no lo cierren, porque no encuentro otra manera más concreta de especificar mi problema. Pero si no hubiera otra forma, pues al menos trabajaré con lo que tengo.

Comment: Pero eso esta correcto, usaste eventos! de igual manera, tus controles deberian exponer eventos o algo para saber que desaparecieron.. o tu interfaz chequear si siguen vivos o no...

Comment: @gbianchi si es correcto lo que dices, mis controles exponen los eventos de manera pública y ahí también tengo instrucciones que se ejecutan correctamente, lo que eso me permite saber que está pasando cuando se lanza mi aplicación. En cuanto a la interfaz, lo que comentas ese es el meollo del asunto no sé como exponerla en la libreria donde está el control de usuario sin que tenga que referenciarla en el proyecto por lo de la dependencia circular, estoy seguro de que hay alguna forma de hacer lo que necesito sólo que sé como indagar sobre ello.

Comment: no entiendo como podes tener una referencia circular.. tu programa principal referencia el control.. porque el control referenciaria a tu programa principal?

Comment: @gbianchi Tengo una libreria donde esta el usercontrol (llamemosla A), otra libreria donde se encuentra la interfaz en donde serán llamados los modulos (llamemosla B), y en el proyecto principal ya tengo referenciada la libreria B. No puedo referenciar A en C (que es el principal digamos) porque A ya esta en B y B ya está en C

Comment: Es una forma muy pero muy rara de hacer un sistema... a menos que b y c sean totalmente reutilizables.. si no es asi, solo es una estructuracion que genera mas problemas que beneficios. Mas alla de eso... no seberia haber referencia circular pq A solo habla con B y B solo con C... los eventos de C deben pasar por B a A.

Comment: @gbianchi te explico brevemente el propósito del porque de ello. Cuando tu creas una solución con un único proyecto en donde conviven formularios, controles de usuario, clases, etc todo en conjunto, al compilar se compila todo en un .exe, si requieres hacer modificaciones a futuro al volver a compilar para tus nuevos cambios ese compilado(.exe) cambia tanto de tamaño(peso) como utilidad. Lo que hago es para que cada modulo se cree y actualice con distintas versiones pero el .exe sea uno sólo y los cambios sean a nivel de libreria (dll) y no de ejecutable.Es la forma típica de VENTAS.

Comment: Son modulos de un sistema general? Entonces requeririas hablar con las dll por interfaces. No termino de comprender si no en que casos requeririas esto (las dll tambien crecen, cambian de utilidad y a veces no son retrocompatibles). Te dejo a ver si conseguis una respuesta. Saludos